# Semantic Phase of compiler

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am trying to make semantic phase for c compiler using lex and yacc. Right now the problem is if I have multiple errors in the c program, it stops after the 1st. What can I do?

Comment: In your yacc file remove the `exit(0);` that is right after the `printf` with the "%s is defined" message?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that you perform the semantic analysis as a separate phase, not as a part of the parsing phase. Use YACC only to build an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), then traverse this tree in a separate function. Said function will have unlimited freedom when it comes to moving around in the tree, as opposed to having to "follow the parsing". As for the specific problem you mentioned, @pmg's comment seems to have pinpointed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one absolute answer to this. A typical way to handle it is to create a special pattern to read symbols until it gets to (for example) a semicolon at the end of a line, giving a reasonable signal that whatever's after that is intended as a new declaration, definition, statement, etc., and then re-start parsing from that point (retaining enough context to know that, for example, you're currently parsing a function body, so you accept/reject input on that basis).